# Mutt `folder-hook macro` Has Too Many Arguments

Tags: macros, mutt

Mutt complains that the following `folder-hook` `macro` has too many arguments.

```
folder-hook +INBOX macro index,pager y "<save-message>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter><enter>" "Archive conversation"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this.

```
folder-hook +INBOX 'macro index,pager y "<save-message>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter><enter>" "Archive conversation"'
```